# Hello, how do you get the mean of all values in a df

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a df with random values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,500,size=(50, 10)))
```

I didn't know if there was an easy way to post the mean of all values within the entire df and post the result? df.mean only searches by a row or column.

My plan was do a groupby for each column then do a mean of that but that would probably be overly burdensome.

Comment: `df.mean().mean()` ?

Comment: @Espi95 has is right. But just in case you want to check it do `df.mean(axis=1).mean()` and you'll see it matches.

Comment: @Epsi95 No, mean isn't associative. E. g. `mean([6, 8, 10]) == 8` but `mean([mean([6, 8]), 10]) == 8.5` with the "mean" function from "statistics" module.

Comment: `df.to_numpy().mean()` will be better since mean is calculated for `flattened` array without axis provided

Comment: @MichaelButscher In this particular case (all columns of the same length, no NaN values) it will work fine.

Comment: @bb1 Oh, you are right. Thanks.